# WPF: enabling button only if one item in ListBox is selected

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox

I am pretty new to WPF, so forgive me a primitive question. I have researched similar questions on how to enable button only if an item is selected in ListBox through binding, but my condition is a bit more complicated.

1. The button needs to be disabled if none of the items in ListBox are selected.
2. The button needs to be enabled if ONE item in Listbox is selected.
3. The button needs to be disabled if multiple items in Listbox are selected.

In other words, it should be enabled only if user selects ONE item in the ListBox.

What I tried:

```xaml
<Button Click="EditSingleEntryButton_Click">Edit selected
    <Button.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger 
                    Binding="{Binding ElementName=entriesListBox, Path=SelectedItems.Count}" 
                    Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

However, this doesn't work - the button stays enabled all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a little bit to your style:

```xml
<Button Click="EditSingleEntryButton_Click">Edit selected
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger 
                    Binding="{Binding ElementName=entriesListBox, Path=SelectedItems.Count}" 
                    Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to change Value to 1 in your example, but otherwise it worked perfectly.

Comment: You're right.
I didn’t paid attention to it.
I have corrected the code due to your comment.